# Missing prefix of assets'url when deploy my Angular app in a subdomain

Tags: css, angular, deployment

I met some issues when deploying my Angular app. I use `<base-href='./'>` , and all the loading of images in html files is good. The issue happens in scss file. Here is my scss file:

```
.landing-page {
  height: 100%;
  background: url('/assets/images/Landing_page.jpg') center center
    no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I deployed my app in a subdomain `host.com/my-app`. The scss will try to get the image through `host.com/assets/image/Landing_page.jpg`* instead of `host.com/my-app/assets/image/Landing_page.jpg` . The subdomain is missing*

Any idea to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, removing the leading slash should work: `url('assets/images/Landing_page.jpg')`. Check it out when you're on a specific page (`host.com/my-app/my-page` should not trigger `host.com/my-app/my-page/assets/images/Landing_page.jpg` but `host.com/my-app/assets/images/Landing_page.jpg`)

Answer (score 0):

In your `angular.json` file in the `"architect"` section of the `"build"` configuration,  change the `"baseHref"` property to subdirectory where your app is hosted.

```
"options": (
    "baseHref": "/my-app"
)
```

and then update assets path in SCSS
You can use `../` to address on level upper and then navigate to assets folder.

```
.landing-page {
  height: 100%;
  background: url('../assets/images/Landing_page.jpg') center center no- 
  repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```